# When and how to use anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, react-native, anonymous-function

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput } from "react-native";

import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const SearchBar = ({ keyWord, onHandleKeyword, onSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.searchBarStyle}>
      <Feather
        style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
        name="search"
        size={24}
        color="black"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.searchStyle}
        placeholder="Search"
        value={keyWord}
        onChangeText={onHandleKeyword}
        onEndEditing={onSubmit}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [keyWord, SetKeyWord] = useState("");
  const [searchApi, errorMessage, news] = useNews();

  return (
    <>
      <SearchBar
        keyWord={keyWord}
        onHandleKeyword={SetKeyWord}
        onSubmit={() => searchApi(keyWord)}
      />
      {errorMessage ? <Text>{errorMessage}</Text> : null}
      <Text>We found {news.length} articles</Text>
    </>
  );
};
```

I dont understand how to use anonymous functions as sometimes another function is passed directly as a prop and sometimes using an anonymous function.
and suppose that function require an argument like in search bar component where i passed onsubmit as a prop,searchApi requires an argument,we dont pass it as a parameter in anonymous function and if change it with onSubmit={searchApi} it doesn't work.I am really confused can someone help

Comment: Whether or not a function is "anonymous" is irrelevant. You have to think about where the function is called and what arguments the functions expect. If you bind a function as an event handler then it will be passed an event object. But `searchApi` doesn't expect an event object it expects some string. So instead of binding `searchApi` as an event handler, you bind another function as event handler which in turn calls `searchApi` with the right argument.

Comment: @FelixKling ohkay..i think i got it..thanks